# cq:include default components in CQ form with server validation

Tags: adobe, aem

I would like to customize start/end of OOTB CQ5 user form component to start with certain custom components pre-populated when the 'form' component is drag/dropped on to the page.

I currently have an over-laid /apps/foundation/components/form  elements with start/end/actions  customized. But I am to figure out way to add a component belonging to the FORM group, to the form  start.......end  to the page whenever a form is added to the page.

I have tried using a `<cq:include path= "customComp"  resourceType="/pathto/customComponent" />`  to the jsp of the `form-end` component, this adds / shows the custom-component on display but does not perform the server-validations as it is not a separate node between the start and end nodes on the page, but a dynamically added one.

This is basically to enforce/mandate the use of my custom captcha component whenever a form is placed on a page.

thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to leave the form creation entirely to the author (as intended with OOTB components) there is no easy way to "sneak in" a mandatory captcha component. Even *if* you managed to put in the captcha component, the author can just delete it or move it out of your paragraph system.

Mingling the captcha with form-end might be possible, but not without reinventing the form-end component pretty much from scratch. I wouldn't want to do that.

I see three options that might be helpful to you:

1. Implement a jcr EventListener that will fire whenever a form is created or changed. Check the form data structure in jcr and when the mandatory captcha component is missing, add it and commit. This type of behaviour is of course a little shady and may suprise authors - but it's gonna work.
2. Build a wrapper form component that contains a paragraph system with a fully pre-configured form, including form-start, captcha and form-end. This approach my even save authors a bit of work and nobody will "forget" about the chaptcha easily. Nothing will stop an evil author from explicitly deleting the catpcha component however.
3. Build an entirely custom form component that does not utilizy any of the OOTB components. In this scenario you have full control over what the author can and cannot do. Most likely you will give up on a lot of flexibility in order to save development time and end up with a mostly static form where the author can edit a few cruicial parts.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. 
 Option #3 is not feasible as I already have authors using the customized OOTB form components.

Option#1 : how do I ensure I place the captcha just before the form-end component , so that no matter what elements the authors place on the page, the captcha is the last component before the submit button

Option #2 :  sounds good,  how do I go about implementing , a rough layout , pesudo-code  would be good.

Also,  when I use the <cq:include> to add the captcha through the form-end jsp,  even if the author tries to delete the captcha it keeps popping backup :)

Comment: to add to my comment, am really able to cq:include the catpcha on form end, however, my main issue is that -  even though the user response is sent on form submit, it does not trigger the server side validation. (like it would if there was physical form captcha node  on the parsys).  Is there a trick to make  server validation mechanism add the captcha resource to the list of resources it checks for server validation?

Comment: Option #1: You implement an EventListener and write code that loops over the form data component nodes in jcr. You write the logic that checks for the captcha and insert it if missing. Ensuring the captcha is inserted at the right place is part of your code and really easy to accomplish.
See https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Node.html#orderBefore(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)